# Adding a line on Barplot PLotly

Tags: python, python-3.x, plotly, bar-chart, line

[Desired output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iaFOi.jpg):

[image]

As you can see in the Picture i already have drawn a Bar plot and i want to add this yellow line as shown in the Picture. but i do end up with a continuous line not being cutted as shown in the Picture
(( one of my Problems is that who iam gonna make for the same value of y-achse 2 different values for x-achse and secondly how can i make the lines be cuted and not continous ))
I have a For loop where from it i get my Y-axes Values and for the X-axes i did define a range

```
def scatter (df):
data = []
line_data = []

for i in range(len(df)):
    json_plot = pd.DataFrame(df['whtever'].values[j])
    xrange_line_1 = list(np.arange(0.75, len(df_main) + 1, 1))
    xrange_line_2 = list(np.arange(1.25, len(df_main) + 1, 1))

    line_data.append(json_plot['balken_linie'][0])
data = [{'type': 'scatter', 'x': xrange_line_2, 'y': line_data, 'mode': 'lines',
         'marker': {'symbol': 'o', 'size': '5', 'color': '#000FF'}}
        ]
return data

data_min = scatter(df)
graph_min = dcc.Graph(figure={
'data': data_min,
'layout': dict(title={'text': 'bar'}, yaxis={'title': {'text': idc1}},
               xaxis={'title': {'text': 'idc2'},

   })

   def page(graph_min):
    return html.Div([
      html.Div([graph_min])])


       app1.layout = page(graph_min)
      if __name__ == '__main__':
       app1.run_server(debug=False)
```

Comment: The questions are worded differently, but you'll find what you need in the link above. If this somehow does not work for you, or if you wildly disagree that it's a duplicate, then let me know and I'll consider reopening your question.